# How to create a printable user form with a new USERID every time one downloads it in php

Tags: php, html, forms, phpmyadmin, userid

How to create a printable user form with a new USERID every time one downloads it in php.
I have created a form in php. But I want it to be available in printable form as well. How to accomplish this, that whenever a user wants the printable form, a new form, with user id gets in the word document under applicant id field.

Comment: What do mean by `new form with user id`? Is this same `user id` used to identify the user from DB or some id to identify the form?

Comment: unique id of every form

Comment: that depend on how unique you want the id. for one, u can use `mt_rand()` to generate 10 digits random numeric. you can store the generated random number to DB for future reference, i.e referring to the form or to avoid the same number being used which is not a problem unless millions of user using your site